# How to Reset Multipart Content-type in a Chain of Rest Assured APIs

Tags: rest-assured

I am having an issue when calling chain of APIs.

1. First API with contentype=JSON - works fine.
2. Second API with contentype=JSON - works fine.
3. Third API with Contentype=Multipart - works fine.
4. Fourth API with Contentype=JSON - not working.

Error:- The reason it is failing due to error.

Failed to hit the URLContent-Type application/json is not valid when using multiparts, it must start with "multipart/" or contain "multipart+".

When 3rd API was hit , I set ContentType as Multipart and added file and it worked perfectly.

But when 4th API was hit , I set ContentType back to JSON, but it failed as the requestspecification still has multipart content attached to the Request

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `RequestSpecification` doesn't have something like `reset()` method, the solution might be using different instances of `RequestSpecification` for each request. The mutation object is not good for you when problem occurs like this one.

**Sample problem:**

```
RequestSpecification reqSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
        .addMultiPart(file)
        .build();

given(reqSpec)
        .post("https://postman-echo.com/post");

given(reqSpec.contentType(JSON))
        .body("test")
        .post("https://postman-echo.com/post");
```

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content-Type application/json is not valid when using multiparts, it must start with "multipart/" or contain "multipart+".`

**Solution:**

```
@Test
void SO_69567028() {
    File file = new File("src/test/resources/1.json");

    given(multipartReqSpec())
            .multiPart(file)
            .post("https://postman-echo.com/post");

    given(jsonReqSpec())
            .body("test")
            .post("https://postman-echo.com/post");
}

public RequestSpecification jsonReqSpec() {
    return new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setContentType(JSON)
            .build();
}

public RequestSpecification multipartReqSpec() {
    return new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setContentType(MULTIPART)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In our [Micronaut-Rest-Assured] application, in one of the unit test we were trying to execute single API endpoint multiple times, by passing different query params & had the similar problem.

1. First API call with query param `/test/xyz?queryParam=1` this was **SUCCESS**
2. Second API call with query param `/test/xyz?queryParam=2` this was failing with `400 Bad Request` since `RequestSpecification` object was not reseting query param values from the first call. To fix this I am doing the following:

**Solution**

```
// Declared this field variable & using it under individual test case as shown below
@Inject
EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;

RestAssured
 .given()
 .port(embeddedServer.getPort())
```

Here is the example code & used `.log()` to see any errors:

```
public void test() {
    RestAssured
     .given()
     .port(embeddedServer.getPort())
     .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "authorization")
     .accept(ContentType.JSON)
     .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
     .queryParams(Map.of("queryParam", 2))
     .when()
     .get("/test/xyz")
     .then()
     .log()             //Will help you see any errors if request fails 
     .body()
     .assertThat()
     .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND);
}
```