# Is there an option to remove the multipart content set in request in REST API(RestAssured) after getting a response?

Tags: rest, rest-assured

In REST API, specifically RestAssured, there is an option to remove the Query params, Headers, Cookies, Form params, Path params which is set in request after getting a response.

Is there an option to remove the multipart content set in request in REST API(RestAssured) after getting a response?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking a way to reuse the `RequestSpecification` object, then No, there are no reset method for all of these config.

You can create new `RequestSpecification` object each time you call the request. Sample here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69569031/7574461